# How can I update DOCKER_OPTS in docker-machine permanently

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

After update to docker-machine, I have no idea how to update `DOCKER_OPTS` in a local **boot2docker docker-machine** and save it permanently

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
dev    *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
```

I tried to ssh into vm with `docker-machine ssh dev`, and update `/etc/docker/default`. But the changes I made are dropped after restart VM with `docker-machine restart dev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of docker-machine 0.5.0, the mirror can be provisioned with `--engine-registry-mirror`

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-registry-mirror http://mirror.dockerhub.com dev
```

> --engine-registry-mirror [--engine-registry-mirror option --engine-registry-mirror option]       Specify registry mirrors to use

Answer (score 10):

If you'd simply like to pass arguments to docker, add them to `EXTRA_ARGS` in `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`. For example:

```
EXTRA_ARGS='
--label provider=virtualbox
--insecure-registry=10.0.0.1:5000
'
```

The docker process is started via `/etc/init.d/docker` which sources `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`. `$EXTRA_ARGS` is passed transparently to the docker process towards the end of `start()`.